# Spark job for Union of pyspark-dataframes not ending

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I'm trying to union all the data-frames that i have using the following code, and then sorting the resultant data-frame in descending order based on column timestamp.

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3]
    df_final = reduce(DataFrame.union, dfs).sort(col('timestamp').desc())
```

The spark job is not ending and is just stuck here, what could be the problem?
I had ran the same code previously about 3 days ago and it had worked fine. Now it's not ending for some reason. There is no error being displayed either. I tried using `unionByName()`, even that is giving the same issues. How do I go about this?

This is what the data-frames look like,

```
+---------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+
|attribute|operation|params                                                                                                                                               |timestamp          |
+---------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+
|profile  |UPDATE   |[member_id -> cqhi6k5lby43pr3iethfmcp8sjq7_STG, easy_id -> 993270334, field -> password_hash, member_uuid -> 027130fe-584d-4d8e-9fb0-b87c984a0c20]   |2020-02-11 19:15:32|
|profile  |UPDATE   |[member_id -> cqhi6k5lby43pr3iethfmcp8sjq7_STG, easy_id -> 993270334, field -> password_hash, member_uuid -> 027130fe-584d-4d8e-9fb0-b87c984a0c20]   |2020-02-11 19:07:34|

+---------+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+
|attribute|operation|params                                                                                                                    |timestamp          |
+---------+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+
|member   |CREATE   |[member_id -> h4m015wf1qxwrogj6d9l2uc5bsa9_STG, easy_id -> 993270331, member_uuid -> ea8e7e39-4a0a-4d41-b47e-70c8e56a2bca]|2020-01-02 09:51:32|
|member   |CREATE   |[member_id -> oeip31lpid9cexl9o5asip92idh7_STG, easy_id -> 993270336, member_uuid -> 9e65124b-cb16-4803-b74d-c0b6a3cb083a]|2020-01-01 10:31:32|

+---------+--------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+
|attribute|operation     |params                                                                                                                                                                                               |timestamp          |
+---------+--------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+
|profile  |CREATE_CARD   |[member_id -> 1s9miu7t6an50fplvvhybow6edx9_STG, easy_id -> 993270335, created_by -> kobo, card_token -> 8236961209881953, member_uuid -> 50d966f2-2820-441a-afbe-851e45eeb13e]                       |2020-02-24 03:07:04|
|profile  |CREATE_CARD   |[member_id -> ajuypjtnlzmk4na047cgav27jma6_STG, easy_id -> 993270327, created_by -> beats, card_token -> 9000141161458480, member_uuid -> 2dec548e-681d-11ea-bc55-0242ac130003]                      |2020-01-11 02:01:53|
```

Comment: what happens if you try `final_df = reduce(lambda a, b: a.union(b), dfs)`?